# cannot match multiple occurrences of character in sed regexp

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to remove As at the end of line.

```
alice$ cat pokusni 
SALALAA
alice$ sed -n 's/\(.*\)A$/\1/p' pokusni 
SALALA
```

one A is removed just fine

```
alice$ sed -n 's/\(.*\)A+$/\1/p' pokusni 
alice$ sed -n 's/\(.*\)AA*$/\1/p' pokusni
SALALA
```

multiple occurrences not:(

I am probably doing just some very stupid mistake, any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one `'s/\(.*[^A]\)AA*$/\1/p'`

---

**Why `+` does not work:**

Because it is just a normal character here.

**Why `'s/\(.*\)AA*$/\1/p'` does not work:**

Because the reg-ex engine is eager, so `.*` would consume as many as `A`s except the final A specified in `AA*`. And `A*` will just match nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n 's/AA*$//p' file
```

This replaces an `A` and zero or more `A`'s at the end of line with nothing.

N.B.

```
sed -n 's/A*$//p file'
```

would produce the correct string however it would operate on every line and so produce false positives.

Comment: This does not print lines that does not contain any `A`, just skips them.

Comment: @Jotne I think the person who asked the question only wanted to print those lines where one or more `A`'s are removed from the end of the line.

Comment: You are correct, he does not tell anything about other lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/AA$/,"A")}1' pokusni 
SALALA
```

EDIT
Correct version, removing all `A` from end of line.

```
awk '{sub(/A*$/,x)}1' pokusni
```

Comment: Multiple occurrences are not only two. And the replacement part should  be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl:

```
> echo "SALALAA" | perl -lne 'if(/(.*?)[A]+$/){print $1}else{print}'
SALAL
```

Comment: This skips lines with no match.